# Jquery class and its function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing discussion panel in asp.net in which I am drawing some spans through javascripts

> `$("#commenttr").after("<tr id="+i+"><td class=\"labelPortion\"></td><td class=\"controlPortion\">" +out[i]+ "</td><td><span style = \"cursor:pointer\" class = \"plblAgreeComment\" id = \"" + ids[i+1] + "\"> Vote Up </span> <span style = \"cursor:pointer\" class = \"plblDisAgreeComment\" id = \"" + ids[i+1] +"\">Vote Down </span><span id = \"ptxtAgreeComment\" >"+ agrees[i+1] + " </span></td></tr>");`

But when I am calling the jquery function

```
$(".plblAgreeComment").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
}
```

Its not working. Please help me.

Comment: Instead of escaping all the `"` you could just use the `'` char to enter your html code after the "#comenttr" item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

You need jQuery `.live()` or `.on()` method to bind events to dynamically created html.

Choose `.live()` or `.on()` depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

> **.live()** Available since jQuery 1.3. Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **.on()** Available since jQuery 1.7. Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

#### Sample

```
$(".plblAgreeComment").live('click', function(){
     alert("hi");
});

$(".plblAgreeComment").on('click', function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

### Update: [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/zqj9k/)

Comment: `.live` isn't the answer here; there's a syntax error, a missing paren, in his event handler. Also, `.live` is [deprecated now](http://api.jquery.com/live/); you should be using `.on` or `.delegate`!

Comment: I updated my answer in the same moment you wrote your comment.

Comment: by adding this now the dynamically spans are not creating :(

Comment: @user1334569 could you provide a jsFiddle ?

Comment: The `.on` sample in your post will not work for elements that are dynamically inserted to DOM.

Comment: <span id="2" class="plblAgreeComment" style="cursor: pointer;"> Vote Up </span>

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `on` since you are adding these items to your DOM dynamically

```
 $(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".plblAgreeComment",click(function(){
            alert("hi");
    });
  });
```

`on` will work for current elements and future elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

`on` is available from jQuery 1.7 onwards, If you are using an older version of jQuery, you should check `live` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: by adding this now the dynamically spans are not creating :(

Comment: @user1334569: I guess, you have some scripts errors then. Check in the firebug console.

Comment: <span id="2" class="plblAgreeComment" style="cursor: pointer;"> Vote Up </span> result from firebug

Comment: @user1334569: Somewhere else you have a console.debug(soemelement). can you post a jsfiddle sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on` in below syntax,

```
$(document).on('click', '.plblAgreeComment', function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

In the above code, use the table selector instead of document select.

Comment: @user1334569 Check the jQuery version you are using. You should use `.delegate` if the jQuery version is < 1.7

Answer (score 0):

two things.. you might have an extra character in class name when generating the html for your row.

```
class = \"plblAgreeCom
```

maybe should be:

```
class =\"plblAgreeCom
```

or you're attaching click handler before the DOM is being modified in which case:

```
 $(".plblAgreeComment").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
}
```

should be:

```
 $(".plblAgreeComment").live("click", function(){
        alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: two things, 1. You are missing `);` in the click handler. 2. `.live` is deprecated as of jquery 1.7. use `.delegate` or `.on`

Comment: by adding this now the dynamically spans are not creating :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind events to dynamically injected DOM elements, you need to use the `on` method so that any new elements are bound to that event listener:

```
 $(".plblAgreeComment").on("click", function(){
    alert("hi");
 }
```

Note: there are other methods, such as `live()` that will achieve similar effects, but they are being deprecated in favor of `on`, which handles this situation for every scenario.